# (Roblox) Is the lobby in the same map as the main game?

Tags: lua, roblox

Before making a game in Roblox, I want to add a lobby. There will be doors in this lobby and when we come into contact with the door, a certain number of people will be teleported to the game. The real problem is where will I make this lobby? Should I do it in an invisible space on the same map? Or is there a different mechanic that I do not know? I am new to this, I need someone to explain all of this. There is, especially about where I will build the lobby.

I haven't done anything about this issue, I'm waiting for something from someone who can help me in this beginning.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends different games use different methods the two methods would be:

1. **Have everything, maps and the lobby in the same place.** This approach would make use of moving the players character from one position to another withing the same place. This is relatively simple. However, this method would have its downside when you have a complex game loop/system. It could be quite complex to handle where players are and teleporting the correct players and then respawning the correct players back to the lobby. Also, if you have multiple game loops running simultaneously you could end up with timing and lag issues.
2. **The second approach is having each game/map in a different place.** This could make it slightly more difficult to start off with, however if you have a  complex game, you would be glad you went through the slightly steep learning curve of handling players and place teleports. It would have the advantage of keeping everything separate and avoiding issues with crossovers and simultaneous running games. It also has the extra advantage that all players on the same map are in the same server, as well as the advantage of making it easier to have different lighting/environment settings for different maps.

So, I would recommend if players separate in your lobby to play different maps you should use different places, but if you game is like Murder Mystery 2 or Arsenal for example you should keep all players in the same place and teleport them to the selected map.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty cloudy question and this is my first time answering on Stackoverflow, but i'll do my best.

Most games with lobbys put it's games in separate [places](https://create.roblox.com/docs/en-us/production/publishing/publishing-experiences-and-places) so the logic and scripts in the lobby don't add up or interfere with the game's own logic. Because for example the game's logic can make it so player's cameras are 1st person locked, while in the lobby you probably would not want that.

So generally what you want to do is make the main place a lobby and make the games or the game itself that people can [teleport](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TeleportService) to into it's own different place!